# Full text indexing on a column in a foreign table

Tags: full-text-search, indexing, myisam

My entire database is in `INNDB`.  I love the features, hands down.  However it doesn't allow full text indexing on TEXT-type columns.  So I have to take my current TEXT column from my main table (`INNODB`) and create a `MYISAM` table and reference back to the original table.  But because `MYISAM` doesn't allow `FK` constraints I realize I've created a potential weakness.  If the original table index changes it won't cascade down into the `MYISAM` table.  Vice versa if I create a `FK` link from the original table to the `MYISAM` table, and the `MYISAM` row is deleted, then I have linked to a nonexistent entry.  The data consistency check is simply not there.

In short, `INNODB` got me too comfortable and dependent on `FK` constraints for my own good.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider not using the MyISAM fulltext indexing at all, and instead using a proper search engine alongside your db.  Lucene/Solr, sphinx and xapian seem to be the leading choices (I've only used Lucene/Solr myself).

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381186/fulltext-search-with-innodb) for more :)

edit: also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638698/mysql-full-text-search-workaround-for-innodb-tables).

Comment: I've not worked with third party search engines before but it should be interesting albeit would add a few days delay in what I thought was going to be a straight-forward table design (stupid scope creep).  But thanks for the rapid reponse, it may be the solution I require.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some sort of framework, the framework can control the referential integrity for you. CakePHP does a nice job of this with their Model classes.