# Most efficient way to search in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with 75,000+ rows with 500+ entries added per day.

Each row has a title and description.

I created an RSS feed which gives you the latest entries for a specific search term (ex. http://site.com/rss.rss?q=Pizza would output an RSS for the search term "Pizza").

I was wondering what would be the best way to write the SQL query for this. Right now I have:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'table' 
WHERE (('title' LIKE %searcherm%) OR ('description' LIKE %searcherm%))
LIMIT 20;
```

But the problem is it takes between 2 to 10 seconds to execute the query.

Is there a better way to write the query, do I have to cache the results (and how would I do  that?) or would changing something in the database structure speed up the query (indexes?)

Comment: might be faster to individual thread/fork the processing into 2 simple querys:

`select from table where title limit 20`
then
`select from table where description limit 20`

kinda thing, then do the joins / list concat with your server side tech

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A relatively simple solution for this would be incorporating a FULLTEXT index on these two fields and subsequently searching by using this index.

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT(title, description);
```

Then would you need to perform a search, you'd do the following:

```
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE MATCH (title, description) AGAINST ('keyterm');
```

Fulltext indexed search is the automatic solution included in most SQL databases. It's much speedier comparing to doing LIKES. This is also optimized for your specific case because you are only interested in natural language search terms.

As well, fulltext index has some limiting algorithm for detecting relevancy. You can read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

**EDIT**

In the alter statement, I missed the fulltext index name, it should be:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT ft_index_name(title, description);
```

Comment: Note that this will only work with MyISAM tables, not InnoDB.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I tested this and it made my searches 14x faster on average!!!!!!!

Comment: Does full text apply for numbers as well?.

Comment: @FrancisAvila Full-Text Search is supported in InnoDB since MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE MATCH (title,description) AGAINST (searchterm);
```

Make sure you add a full text index on title, description together.

Dont try to reinvent the wheel. `MATCH` and `AGAINST` are [provided by mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) to do exactly that and to make your life easy. However, note full text search works on MyISAM tables. You [can workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638698/mysql-full-text-search-workaround-for-innodb-tables) for InnoDb too. You can simply add FT index by altering table like:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT(title,description);
```

Comment: This is the only answer that would work. Mention that you need to add a fulltext index to these columns and you must use MyISAM tables.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a query with `LIKE '%term%'` the indexes can't be used. They can be used only if you use a query like `'term%'`. Think about an address book with tabs, you can find really fast contacts starting with letter `L`, but to find contacts with a `on` somewhere in the word, you've to scan the whole addressbook.

The better alternative could be to use full text indexes:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX title_desc
ON table (title, description)
```

And then in the query:

```
SELECT title, description FROM table
WHERE MATCH (title, description) AGAINST ('+Pizza')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with JohnB's or gtr32x's answer (Full Text Indexing). To complement their answer, there's a manual way to create a simple full text index that's simple and it's super fast...

Split title and description into keywords, and place them in a `Keywords` table, which has a foreign key to the original RSS article. Make sure the keyword column in `Keywords` is indexed. The you can do something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ra.* 
FROM RssArticle ra
INNER JOIN Keywords k ON k.ArticleID = ra.ArticleID
   WHERE k IN ( 'SearchTerm1', 'SearchTerm2', 'SearchTerm3')
LIMIT 20;
```

And it's fast!

Answer (score 0):

Try either of the following four queries:

```
select * from myTable where concat_ws(' ',title,description) like '%pizza%';
select * from myTable where concat_ws(' ',title,description) regexp '.*pizza+.*';
select title,description from myTable where concat_ws(' ',title,description) like '%pizza%';
select title,description from myTable where concat_ws(' ',title,description) regexp '.*pizza+.*';
```

the point is to use concat before searching

Comment: this was about 2x faster but not as fast as MATCH AGAINST

Answer (score -2):

A few pointers: Drop the * in your select statement and pull only the searched criteria, and make sure to add indexes to the columns that are getting searched.

```
SELECT `title`,`description` 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `title` LIKE '%$searchterm%' OR `description` LIKE '%$searchterm%' LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: "Drop the * in your select statement and pull only the searched criteria" - well how do you know what he wants to retrieve?

Comment: I don't, but based on his WHERE clause, I can determine he needs at LEAST title, and description. Regardless, it's always better to specify your tables rather then the wildcard, he is asking how to speed up the query and eliminating wildcards is the first step.

Comment: there's a LIMIT 20.. I doubt that it will make any measurable difference

Comment: Normal indexes will not help you here because of the leading '%'. They will only take up space and not be used. (Also, your searchterm is not properly escaped.)  You can use a fulltext index and the `MATCH` operator, but only on `MyISAM` tables.

Answer (score -2):

1. Did you create an index for `title` and for `description`?
2. You should consider [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) for Full Text Search capabilities.

---

*Thanks for the comment Tyler.*

I restate my answer:

1) Create an index on `title` and `description` columns, but your query would be limited to the example below, and that's not ideal for finding all relevant rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'table' 
WHERE title LIKE 'searcherm%' OR description LIKE 'searcherm%'
LIMIT 20;
```

2) As others have mentioned, use [MySQL Full-Text Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792875/which-sql-query-is-better-match-against-or-like), but you are limited to MyISAM table engine, as it isn't available for InnoDB.  However, you can mix engines in MySQL, so you can make this table MyISAM, even if all your other tables are InnoDB.

3) Use an external Full-Text Search engine, such as [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).  This will give you more relevant search results (MySQL Full-Text Search leaves much to be desired), it will perform better, and it abstracts the burden of Full-Text Searching away from your database.

Comment: Index won't help here. Like '%foo%' never uses an index. That's his REAL problem.