# Search wildcard multiple columns in Rails using one param

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. I have the following table:

```
name                 address
=======================================
Hilton Hotel         New York, USA
Hilton Hotel         Paris, France
Mandarin Hotel       Chicago, USA
Le Meridien Hotel    New York, USA
```

and the following query:

```
term = "%#{params[:term]}%"
shops = Shop.limit(10).where("name LIKE ? OR address like ?", term, term)
```

My expected result is this:

```
Search - "Hilton"
Result - "Hilton Hotel, New York, USA"; "Hilton Hotel, Paris, France"

Search - "Hilton USA"
Result - "Hilton Hotel, New York, USA"

Search - "New York"
Result - "Hilton Hotel, New York, USA"; "Le Meridien Hotel, New York, USA"
```

How should I rewrite my query?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't match single string which contains substring of two attributes unless you have some separator. In your search query atleast you should take comma separated values. Like `Hilton, USA`. SO you can split on `,`. If its single string like `New York` then you give to match both attribute with same string.

Comment: I don't think that is an option I want to take in.

Comment: It may not be the best way, but you can split the string on `,` and space, then match the two columns with each split parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use another workaround for this.

I create another column `for_autocomplete` and concatenate the `name` and `address` into it. Every time a record is created/updated, it will create/update `for_autocomplete` accordingly. Then I just search through the `for_autocomplete` column.

Answer (score 1):

You could use MySQL's MATCH AGAINST. There's no direct support in Rails, but you can always roll your own custom query in Rails using

```
YourModel.find_by_sql("SELECT ... WHERE MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)")
```

or a bit more Rails style (have not tested this):

```
YourModel.where("MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)")
```

For more information, have a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html

**EDIT:**
I'd split the input string by space, comma, dot, etc. and then use MATCH AGAINST to get all results. So if you have this table:

```
      col1 | col2
      -----------
row1: a c  | a
row2: a d  | b e
row3: b e  | a d
row4: b    | b c
```

And the user types `a` as input. You should do

```
MATCH(col1, col2) AGAINST ('a')
```

This will return:

```
row1: 'a c', 'a'
row2: 'a d', 'b e'
row3: 'b e', 'a d'
```

Comment: This only can be used on MyISAM table. I am using InnoDB. :(

Comment: Maybe you could use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638698/mysql-full-text-search-workaround-for-innodb-tables

Comment: Since MySQL 5.6, this is supported on InnoDB as well. Tested and it works great.